# Convert string in javascript using moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

i try convert string to moment and check is same.

```
    protected showEvent(event: IEvent, hour: Moment): boolean {
        let formatDate: Moment = moment(event.futureDate);
        console.log('--> formatDate', formatDate);
        console.log('--> hour', hour);

        return formatDate.isSame(hour, "hour"); // return true is same
    }
```

this console result

```
--> formatDate: Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "07-24-2017 07:00:00.000", _isUTC: false, _pf: Object, _locale: Locale…}_d: Mon Jul 24 2017 07:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)_i: "07-24-2017 07:00:00.000"}

--> hour: Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _pf: Object, _locale: Locale, _d: Tue Jul 25 2017 07:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)…}
```

How can I convert the date to see if the time is the same?

edit: the whole looks like this

```
protected showEvent(event: IEvent, hour: Moment): boolean {
    return moment(event.futureDate).hour() == hour.hours()
}
```

Comment: you want to check if the time is exactly same?

Comment: What is being returned?

Comment: So I wanted to compare hours.

Here is the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45312889/5582705

Thanks for the help

Comment: [`formatDate.isSame(hour, "hour")`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) returns `true` if `formatDate` and `hour` have the same year, month, day and hour. If you want to display the value of a moment object, you can use [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try comparing the hour value alone.

`return formatDate.hours() == hour.hours()`

If you are looking to compare the entire date you can compare the other values e.g. `minutes()`